# Line and load regulation testing of flyback converter

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, flyback

I have designed a flyback converter with dual outputs. I have the following queries for performing line & load regulation tests for the same.

1)To perform line regulation on 25 V rail, should I keep the 5.7V open (no load) or load the 5.7V rail(percentage of load??)

2)Similarly to perform line regulation on 5.7 V rail, should I keep the 25 V open (no load) or load the 25V rail(percentage of load??).

3) For load regulation test on 25V rail with a min and max load. should I load the 5.7V(percentage of load??) or keep it open(no load)

4)For load regulation test on 5.7V rail with a min and max load. should I load the 25V(percentage of load??) or keep it open(no load)

Anyone Kindly advise on how to perform line & load regulation test for dual output flyback converter

[image]

[image]

Comment: First off, the schematic you have provided is a bit...skinny. Could you share the sec. side winding configuration at least? Now regarding the tests, it depends on what your design specs say. Most of these tests are run at nominal conditions, e.g. with fully loaded outputs. I would personally test line/load with all loaded outputs and then alternate the load condition.Usually, line regulation is ok in multi-output flyback converters but load reg. suffers from current sharing at the main switch turn-off. A weighted feedback scheme can help a little in this case.

Comment: @VerbalKint I have attached the secondary side of design

Comment: Thank you, it looks like an AN from PI. The regulation seems to be weighted on the 5.7-V and 25-V rails via a TL431 biased from the 5.7-V rail. I would look at the input performance at nominal loading conditions, e.g. with 1.25 A and 620 mA as shown in the schematic diagram. For the load response at nominal input voltage, it depends on what is expected and what the load absorbs on both rails. If you expect 0 to 100% steps on the 5.7-V rail, then test for it while the second output is 100% loaded. 50 to 100% will already be a good indication of the performance though as 0 to 100% is tough.